# how to launch startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS")); on Samsung Galaxy phones?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-permissions

I have an app where I am requesting Notifications Access Permission from Users. In order to take users directly to the screen where they give access, I launch the following intent:

`startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));`

In a Stock Android (also in Moto X), it brings up the following screen. I guess Samsung's specific OEM ROM does not support this intent.

On my MotoX, I can get to the screen the following way: `Settings -> Sound & Notification (under Device) --> Notification Access`

[image]

**Question is** - How to launch this Notification Access screen on Samsung Galaxy S5/S6, i.e. the Galaxy Phones?

Comment: Did you find answer to this? And how can you launch that permission screen on Samsung phones?

Comment: Nope @abhinav, not programmatically. But here's how to do it on a Samsung Note 5: https://medium.com/@focusonapp/how-to-enable-notifications-access-for-focuson-on-samsung-galaxy-phones-ac231e7e77d5#.81ebgumvs